# fileSystemWatcher doesn't work when watching for created zip files

Tags: c#, file, io, filesystemwatcher

I have been using fileSystemWatcher for c# to track when a zip file has been downloaded, the problem is that the name of the file never gets output to result.Name. Why is this??

```
public ResultsDetails ExportCallsToCsv()
            {
                var downloadsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Downloads";
                ExportToCsvButton.Click();
                using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(downloadsDirectory))
                {
                    watcher.Filter = "*.zip";
                    var result = watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, 10000);
                    CsvFilePath = $@"{downloadsDirectory}\{result.Name}".Replace("_", "-");
                }
    return new ResultsDetails(ActionResult.Passed, "Csv file created succesfully.");
            }
```

Why does result.Name never get filled? I've attempted to put an endless while loop inside the using block which breaks when result.Name gets filled, but to still no avail. It just halts forever when I do that.

Comment: What is this: `ExportToCsvButton.Click();` (synchronously) doing? Is the path correct? Have you tried another (non-*special*) path?

Comment: I would suggest to experiment with other `WatcherChangeTypes` values, or remove the `"*.zip"` `Filter`. Probably the created file has initially a different extension, and it's renamed to `.zip` after the compression has completed.

Comment: The button downloads a zip file containing a csv to the downloads location

Comment: Does the button event handler *complete* the download? Or does it just start it?

Comment: It just starts it

Answer (score 1):

`FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged` is a synchronous/blocking method and is unable to capture the file change that was triggered on the same thread.

Here's an example of your code in a small test program.  This will not work (as you pointed out).

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directory = "C:\\test";
        File.Copy("C:\\test\\source.txt", "C:\\test\\new_file.txt");

        using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory))
        {
            watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            var result = watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, 10000);
            if (result.Name is null)
            {
                // This is always printed.
                Console.WriteLine("No name");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here's a small sample program that does work.  This version handles the FileSystemWatcher events asynchronously.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directory = "C:\\test";

        using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory, "*.txt"))
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // *** Be sure to include this!
            watcher.Created += Watcher_Created; // *** This is different, too.

            File.Delete("C:\\test\\new_file.txt");
            File.Copy("C:\\test\\source.txt", "C:\\test\\new_file.txt");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("All done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Detected {e.Name} is {e.ChangeType}.");
    }
```

Comment: ah. I'm using a testing framework which is unable to run asynchronously. Looks like I'll have to use Thread.Sleep() to just wait for the file to download. Thank you

Comment: Isn't the problem just that the file was created *before* you started to watch for it?

Comment: no. No matter when the download button is pressed, No changes get detected

Comment: @jamie - No, you need to use `FileSystemWatcher` in an async fashion (by subscribing handlers to the events, ie, `Watcher_Created`.  You can register this event handler, THEN copy the file, and you will receive the event w/ filename.

Comment: You cannot declare a FileSystemWatcher with a `using` statement when you use the event-driven version. You'll dispose of it right after.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me @SteveWong the Watched_Created function never gets called. I'm required to return the resultsDetails after this, and somewhere down the line, Csv file path is supposed to get read, causing an error. Any more advice?

Comment: @jamie - bummer.  Ok, can you get the small sample program to work using FileSystemWatcher?  Also, @Jimi is right, you need to be careful about when the FileSystemWatcher component is Disposed after the `using` block.  I wonder if that is what is happening in your test.

Comment: @jamie See my comment above yours: remove the `using` block. Also, note that the functionality is the same as the synchronous version. If you create the archive synchronously, you initialize the watcher only after the file has been created. If you initialize the event-driven watcher beforehand, you have a *concurrency* issue, since the notification is generated when file is created, but it may (will) not be written entirely.